# Find Terminal Services user's document folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, terminal-services

I'm trying to allow users to use their local scanners with a Terminal Server via an IIS aspx page containing a browser plugin. The plugin can scan files and pass the data to an aspx page which uploads files to the server.

I'm using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get a string containing the name of the remote user. How can I find the user's documents folder on the terminal server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a bit of progress. Here's a way to find a the path for a known username using Powershell:

```
$user = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'known_username' }
cd 'HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'
$key = Get-Item $user.SID
$saveLocation = $key.GetValue("ProfileImagePath")
```

Here's the C# version:

```
string loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
Regex r = new Regex(@"\w+[\\]");
string userName = r.Replace(loginName, "");
throw new System.ArgumentException("Debug: '" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString() +"'", "userName");
SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "name='" + userName + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);
string sid = "";
foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get()) 
{
    sid = mObject["SID"].ToString();
    break; //mSearcher.Get() is not indexable. Behold the hackyness!
}
string saveLocation = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList\\" + sid,
    "ProfileImagePath", null).ToString();
```

C# is not my native tongue; there are probably methods of accomplishing this that are less blunt. But it *does* work.